# CMD deleting folder recursively (i.e. same folder name in multiple locations)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Due to a Dreamweaver setting mess-up, we've had thousands of "_notes" folders pop up in our websites dev & qa areas. There's too many to delete through Windows Explorer - everything just locks up - so I was hoping to run a batch script to sort it out for us once and for all. The problem is I'm not entirely sure that "rd /S" will do what I want.

My understanding is that rd /S will look recursively in the folder I tell it, so if I say:

```
rd /S r:/<siteName>/_notes/
```

then it will just look in the _notes folder and delete what's in there and then try to move further down that tree. What I need is a script that would take into account things like the following:

```
r:/<siteName>/_notes/
r:/<siteName/<someFolder>/_notes/
r:/<siteName/<someOtherFolder>/_notes/
r:/<siteName/<someFolder>/<someSubFolder>/_notes/
r:/<siteName/<someFolder>/<iThinkIveMadeMyPoint>/_notes/
```

Hope I made sense...

I found this in another thread, but it doesn't work with folders with a . in the name, so it's no use for site names...

```
 @Echo OFF
 REM Important that Delayed Expansion is Enabled
 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 REM This sets what folder the batch is looking for and the root in which it starts the search:
 set /p foldername=Please enter the foldername you want to delete: 
 set /p root=Please enter the root directory (ex: C:\TestFolder)
 REM Checks each directory in the given root
 FOR /R %root% %%A IN (.) DO (
    if '%%A'=='' goto end   
    REM Correctly parses info for executing the loop and RM functions
    set dir="%%A"
    set dir=!dir:.=!
    set directory=%%A
    set directory=!directory::=!
    set directory=!directory:\=;!   
    REM Checks each directory
    for /f "tokens=* delims=;" %%P in ("!directory!") do call :loop %%P)
    REM After each directory is checked the batch will allow you to see folders deleted.
   :end
 pause
 endlocal
 exit
 REM This loop checks each folder inside the directory for the specified folder name. This allows you to check multiple nested directories.
 :loop
 if '%1'=='' goto endloop
 if '%1'=='%foldername%' (
    rd /S /Q !dir!
    echo !dir! was deleted.
 )
  SHIFT
  goto :loop
  :endloop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

read `HELP FOR`, `HELP SET` and `HELP IF`

note that `FOR /D /R` will recursively walk the directory tree.

note also that `%~na` is the funny syntax to extract the *name* part of a full *path*.

so, putting this little pieces togethere, try this command on the command line

```
for /d /r %a in (*) do @if %~na==_notes @echo rd %a
```

after careful testing, remove the `echo` command.

Comment: nice single line solution ;-).  i tried
 
`for /d /r %a in (_notes) do @echo rd %a`

but now i do not know why this 'solution' does not work

Comment: changed from    "echo rd %a"   to  "echo rd /s/q %a"    to delete directories that are not empty

Answer (score 0):

This command has worked for me and I hope this could help. Switch to the common root folder, and type in CMD:

```
for /d /r . %d in (<folder name>) do @if exist "%d" rd /s/q "%d"
```

Change the  to the name of folder you want to remove. Then all children folders with this name would be removed.